# Determine whether $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is separable or complete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces, separable-spaces

> Let $d_\omega$ be the metric on $\mathbb{R}^\omega := \{(a_k)_{k\geq 1} : a_k\in \mathbb{R}\}$ given by $d_\omega(a,b) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{|a_k-b_k|}{2^k(1+|a_k - b_k|)}.$

> Determine whether $(\mathbb{R}^\omega, d_\omega)$ is separable.

> Determine whether $(\mathbb{R}^\omega, d_\omega)$ is complete.

I know that for a sequence $(a_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^\omega, d_\omega(a_n,b) \to 0$ if and only if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |a_{n,k} - b_k|$ as $n\to\infty$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, but I'm not sure if this is useful for showing that the metric space is separable. I also know that the rational numbers are countable, countable unions of countable sets are countable, and that the rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}.$ These facts are used to show $(\ell_1, d_1)$ and $(\ell_2, d_2)$ are separable, but I'm not sure if they're useful here.

As for the second part, to show the metric space is complete, it suffices to show that every Cauchy sequence in the metric space converges in the metric space. Suppose $(a_n)$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. Let $\epsilon > 0.$ Choose $M\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ so that $k,l\geq M\Rightarrow d_\omega( a_k, a_l) < \epsilon.$ I was wondering if I might be able to mimic the proof that $(\ell_\infty, d_\infty)$ is complete using the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete?

Comment: I'm sure this has an answer on this site but I have no skill in searching here  so I'm not going to call a duplicate. Perhaps you could search "Product Of Metric Spaces".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet can you please share any ideas you have? I've been stuck on this problem for a long time now.

Comment: If you are comfortable with topological arguments: let $d(a,b) = \frac{|a-b|}{1+|a-b|}$  be a metric on $\mathbb{R}$; then this metric is equivalent to the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}$, so $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ is separable. Now observe that $(\mathbb{R}^\omega , d_\omega)$ has the product topology of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (\mathbb{R}, d)$, and, in the product topology, the countable product of separable spaces is separable.

Comment: @JoseAvilez that's nice, but I was wondering if you could stick more closely to the definitions of separability and explicitly find a separable subspace? I can show that $(|a-b|)/(1+|a-b|)$ is a metric. In fact, if $d$ is a metric and $F$ is any function so that $F$ is positive definite, increasing, and $F(x+y)\leq F(x) + F(y)$ for nonnegative $x,y$, then if we let $d_2$ be defined by $d_2(x,y) = F(d(x,y)), d_2$ is a metric.

Comment: @JoseAvilez can you at least explicitly provide a countable dense subset of the set?

Comment: @FredJefferson Sure, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Separability**

Let $c_{0,0}^{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the sequences with finite support with rational coefficients. This set is countable. For density, let $x = (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \mathbb{R}^\omega$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Since $$\frac{|x-y|}{1 + |x-y|} \leq 1$$
the comparison test for series tells us that the metric is well defined. Thus, we may get an $N$ so large that $x^N = (x_1, \ldots , x_N, 0, 0, \ldots )$ is within $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ of $x$. Now, get rationals $q_1, \ldots , q_N$ with $|x_i - q_i| < \frac{\epsilon}{N}$. I claim $q = (q_1, \ldots , q_N, 0, 0, \ldots )\in c_{0,0}^{\mathbb{Q}}$ satisfies $d(x,q) < \epsilon$. Indeed:

$$d(x,q) \leq d(x,x^N) + d(x^N, q) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{|x_i-q_i|}{2^j(1+|x_i-q_i|)} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \sum_{j=1}^N |x_i-q_i| < \epsilon$$
As desired.

**Completeness**
Let $(x^n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb{R}^\omega$ be Cauchy. Then, for each fixed $j$: $$\frac{|x_j^n - x_j^m|}{2^j(1 + |x_j^n-x_j^m|)} < d(x^n,x^m)$$
so that $(x_j^n)_{n=1}^\infty $ is Cauchy in $\left( \mathbb{R}, \frac{|\cdot |}{1+|\cdot|} \right)$, which is a complete metric space. Hence, $(x_j^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges, say to $x_j$. Let $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3, \ldots) \in \mathbb{R}^\omega$. I claim $x^n \to x$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, pick $R$ so large that $$\sum_{j=R+1}^\infty \frac{|x_j^n - x_j|}{2^j(1 + |x_j^n - x_j|)} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ Now, pick $k$ such that, for $1 \leq j \leq R$ $$\frac{|x_j^k - x_j|}{1 + |x_j^k-x_j|} < \frac{\epsilon 2^{j-1}}{R}$$ which we can do by coordinate-wise convergence. Finally, $$d(x^k, x) = \sum_{j=1}^R \frac{|x_j^n - x_j|}{2^j(1 + |x_j^n - x_j|)} + \sum_{j=R+1}^\infty \frac{|x_j^n - x_j|}{2^j(1 + |x_j^n - x_j|)} < \sum_{j=1}^R \frac{\epsilon}{2R} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$
Which shows that the given space is complete.